# Unable to insert Data inside Microsoft Access Database [C#]

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb, oledbconnection

I have an Access File that has 6 fields like this:

```
ID, Designation, Price, Group, Weight, DeliveryTime
```

In my code, I first created an OleDbConnection and an OleDbCommand inside my Database Class.

```
private OleDbConnection _connection = new OleDbConnection(parameter);
private OleDbCommand _command;
```

After that I execute the WriteData Method.

```
public void WriteData(string tableName, string designation, string price, string group, string weight, string deliveryTime)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + 
            tableName + " (ID, Designation, Price, Group, Weight, deliveryTime) 
            VALUES (@id, @des, @price, @group, @weight, @deliveryTime)";

        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GetNextHighestItemNumber());
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@des", designation);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@group", group);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@weight", weight);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deliveryTime", deliveryTime);

        OpenConnection();
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

But there is no new Data inside my Database. I also tried it this way:

```
public void WriteData(string tableName, string designation, string price, string group, string weight, string deliveryTime)
    {
        _command.Connection = _connection;
        _command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + 
            tableName + " (ID, Designation, Price, Group, Weight, deliveryTime) 
            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", GetNextHighestItemNumber());
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Designation", designation);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", price);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Group", group);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Weight", weight);
        _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("DeliveryTime", deliveryTime);

        OpenConnection();
        _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        CloseConnection();

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
```

Do I overlook something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you get your "Success" message?

Comment: Yes I get the Success Message.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. Is it 1? Are you sure you are checking the same database that your application is connecting to? It is a common problem to overwrite your mdb file every time the app is run if you have it in your solution and it build action copy always.

Comment: Well, the Value I am getting is 0.

Comment: What's the table structure? It's likely you're not allowed to insert values into the ID column.

Comment: They are all "Short Text"

Comment: Maybe it is because you are not clearing your command parameters, you are adding more and more every time you call WriteData .

Comment: But it should be cleared after I rebuild the project.

Comment: Your ID is _Short Text_? And you're using some function to get the highest number and then increment it on a text field? That sounds like a recipe for disaster. Note that `Max(ID)` on a text field will return `9` even though a value of `10` (or `100000`) exists.

Comment: It may not be the root of your problem but it is a problem. You need to clear the parameters or add them only one time.

Comment: Don't worry! I'm in school and I have to learn "string manipulation".
The ID is "DES00001", "DES00002" and so on. Our teacher said we should declare the ID as Short Text.

Comment: I added "_command.Parameters.Clear();" after the Query Execute

Comment: The only problems I can think of would throw an exception so I can't explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Your teacher should also tell you never (as in _never_) to store numeric and date values like _price_, _weight_, and _deliveryTime_.

Comment: As I told you, we students know that you should never do that. But, can you help me with my problem?

Comment: If you want to know how I solved the problem then look at my Answer. Maybe someone knows why you have to create a new OleDbCommand object.

Answer (score 0):

I added a NEW OleDbCommand and applied the connection, command, and Parameters to it.

```
public void WriteData(string tableName, string designation, string price, string group, string weight, string deliveryTime)
{
    _command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + 
        tableName + " (ID, Designation, Price, Group, Weight, deliveryTime) 
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    OleDbCommand addDataCommand = new OleDbCommand(_command.CommandText, _connection);     

    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", GetNextHighestItemNumber());
    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("Designation", designation);
    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", price);
    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("Group", group);
    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("Weight", weight);
    addDataCommand .Parameters.AddWithValue("DeliveryTime", deliveryTime);

    OpenConnection();
    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    CloseConnection();

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Success");
}
```

It seems that you have to create a new Command and execute it because it's working now.

Thanks for your help in the comments.